# How can i open a component in new Tab in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a dropdown which will a client list. Based on what i select in the dropdown i want to open a new tab for that particular client. Is there any way to do it?
I tried window.open(), while it works but it appends URl to http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]. I dont what object to get appended in the URL. TIA

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? An object doesn't translate like that, you'll have to stringify it, if it's valid. Otherwise if you use the react router, you may be able to take advantage of the `to` prop

Comment: why not just `<a href="some route" target="_blank"`? then let the route render the correct component?

Comment: handleSelect = (name, value, text, event) => {
        this.setState({
            label: text
        });
        let filter = { name: name, value: value };
        if(text === "CNC")
            window.open(<Tableau></Tableau>);
        //this.props.action(filter, event);
        this.handleOpen(event);

    }
I am passing component in window.open(). I am sorry if its naive, i am new to react.

Answer (score 6):

The `window.open()` [method accepts a URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), so passing a component/javascript in the way that you require is not possible.

Consider setting up a route, say `/popup-tableau` that exclusively renders the `<Tableau />` component, and then call:

```
window.open('/popup-tableau')
```

The idea here is that your application will open the new window, and a second instance of your application will be started (inside the new window), and directed to the route `/popup-tableau` which will display the `<Tableau />` component in the way you require.

Comment: It worked thanks. Also if you could help: Can i call a method in another component from a dropdown component method? TIA

Comment: Hi @Rahul glad this worked for you! That should be possible, could you please post your code for this dropdown in a new question and provide me with the link so I can get a better idea of what you are trying to do? Also, if you found this answer useful please consider accepting it :-)

Comment: Really Appreciate your help. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976248/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-another-component-and-pass-the-query-parametres.

Comment: @Rahul you're welcome! (you can also accept answers by clicking the tick outline)

Comment: How would you pass in props to the child component?

Comment: @Jesse you could pass data to the child component via the query string. eg, `window.open('/popup-tableau?yourProp=someData&yourOtherProp=1234')`

The react application at `popup-tableau` would then look for, and apply, data from the query string to say, the root component that is rendered