# How can i call a method in another component and pass the query parametres

Tags: reactjs

Here is my problem. I have a dropdown which will have list of options. On selecting an option, a new Tab will open which will have a Tableau dashboard of that particular option. How can i solve the query parameter thing since i need to send back end the query string(Option_ID).

Here is my Dropdown Component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './Dropdown.css';

class DisplayContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleSelection = this.handleSelection.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        displayValue: 'Select a Client'
      }
    }

    handleSelection(item){
      this.setState({
        displayValue: item.client
      });

        window.open('/client');
    }
    render(){
    const listItems = this.props.options;
      return (
        <div className='dropdown-width'>
          <DropDown options={listItems} value={this.state.displayValue} onClick={this.handleSelection} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default DisplayContainer;
```

Right now i am able to open a new tab by simple(dummy) routing. I need a way to send ID to server side. Can you please help me with it.

Comment: Hi Rahul,  if I understand your question, could you solve this by something like: 
`window.open('/client?option_id' = item.id);`

Comment: Yeah i can but that would mean different components for different options. I was thinking to use single Dashboard Component and changing its option_id. Is that possible?

Comment: You should find that use of the query string in this way : `?option_id=..` means that your application routes to the same component which would allow you to reuse the component for each option. It would therefore be up to your component to look at that query string value `option_id` and respond to it accordingly - does that make sense?

Comment: Ohh yes...i can pull the id from props.params. Perfectly makes sense. Again thanks a ton!

Comment: you're welcome - please consider accepting the answer if this has been helpful!

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this, you could make use of the query string when opening your new tab/window with `window.open()`.

So, updating your `handleSelection()` method like this would achieve what you need:

```
handleSelection(item){
  this.setState({
    displayValue: item.client
  });

  window.open('/client?option_id=' + item.id);
}
```

Then, you'd just need to update the `<Tableau />` component that is displayed at the `/client` route, so that is reads and reacts to the value of the `option_id` variable in the query string.

Hope this helps!